# AppBar button-Click event is raised before the LostFocus event of the TextBox in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Textbox tha has LostFocus event, one button that has Click event, and one appbarButton with click event. 
Whenever I click on the non-appbar button, if the focus was in the text box it always calls the Lostfocus event before click event. But. when I do same thing by clicking an appbar button, it never allows Lostfocus to run before its click event.
I tried making LostFocus as async method but nothing is working the way I want.
Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AllowFocusOnInteraction = true of the AppBar button. This will trigger the LostFocus event first if any field losses focus before the Click of the AppBar button.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the `AppBarButton` without affecting the focus of other controls is a design.

If you want to do some processing in `TextBox.LostFocus`, you can do this:

```cs
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as AppBarButton).Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
    // do other things...
}
```

After manually setting the focus to the `AppBarButton`, the `TextBox` will lose focus, and your task will continue normally.

Comment: Thanks, But I used AllowFocusOnInteraction = true as a button property to make this work.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, it's great. You can mark your answer.